# Exponential issue in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.0

I'm facing an issue with the exponential function in postgresql. If I use this select statement `select exp(5999)`, I'm getting:

```
ERROR: value out of range: overflow 
SQL state: 22003
```

If I use this select statement `select exp(5999.1)`, I'm getting the exponential result.

In other case if I use this statement `select exp(9999.1)`, I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: argument for function "exp" too big
SQL state: 22003
```

Please let me know why this issue happening and what is the solution for this kind of issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your first problem is caused by the fact that the output type of `exp()` is the same as the input type. Because you're using an integral value, it's complaining that the result won't fit in an integer.

That's likely why `exp(5999.1)`, and probably `exp(5999.0)` works, the floating point type has a larger range.

Your second error is slightly different, it's complaining not of overflow during the calculation, but of the fact the *input* argument is too large. It's possible that it has some sanity checking on the input somewhere.

Even floating point values run out of range eventually. e<sup>9999</sup> is somewhere around 10<sup>4300</sup>, a rather large number and probably well beyond what you'd expect to see in a database application.

In fact, I'd be interested in the use case of such large numbers in a database application. This sounds like something better suited to a bignum package like [MPIR](http://www.mpir.org/).

Comment: Thank very much.. is there any solution to avoid the ERROR: argument for function "exp" too big issue?

Comment: Well, you could rethink _why_ you need such large numbers in a database application. Unless you're working for the US government or Bill Gates, I can't see the use case :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you pass an `INTEGER` argument the `exp()` function will try to return `double precision` value. Just above value n=709 it will reach the limit of 64-bit floating point number (about 10^308) and fail to calculate the e^n. The solution is to pass your argument with `NUMERIC` type:

```
SELECT EXP(710); -- failure!
SELECT EXP(710::NUMERIC); -- OK
SELECT EXP(5999.1::NUMERIC); -- huge but OK
```

---

EDIT!

As for the **ERROR: argument for function "exp" too big SQL state: 22003**. I've tried to write a work-around. Just run this:

```
SELECT n, POWER(EXP(1::NUMERIC), n) FROM (VALUES(9998), (9999), (10000)) AS foo (n)
```

and it will work. But then change 9999 to 9999.1 and you will get that stupid error again. This is ridiculous! 9999.1 is *too big* but 10000 is fine :D It looks like Postgres doesn't like decimal point in `POWER()`'s argument. Sorry but I can't fix that.

One solution would be to use the arithmetic property of power and write `POWER(POWER(EXP(1::NUMERIC), n*10), 0.1)` but that value combination is still too big for Postgres' implementation of power. Good luck with your battle.

Comment: thank you.. but is there any solution for the ERROR:  argument for function "exp" too big?